# Windows UWP Platform : how to specify the filename when printing from an app

Tags: pdf, uwp

I'm currently coding an UWP application on Windows 10 build 10586 (Threshold 2).
I'm printing PDF document from my app, and want to set a specific filename to the output print.
In Windows 10 build 10.10240, I was able to do that using the PDF printing api, using `public PrintTask CreatePrintTask(
  string title, 
  PrintTaskSourceRequestedHandler handler
)`
 with title being the fileName (eg c:\user\XXX\Documents\MyPdfFile.pdf)

Now in Windows 10 TH2, with the same code, this 'title' parameter is being displayed as the printPreview page title, and is not used anymore afterthat. Meaning that the user has to input a fileName for the file to be saved (in the standard file picker window).

Anybody has encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out CreatePrintTask has consistent behaviors on Windows Phone with 10586 and 10240, the title parameter is for the file name, and pdf file is saved automatically, without a FilePicker prompt.
[image]

However, on a Windows 10.10586 Desktop, the "title" parameter is for the print dialog title, and user has to select a file name in the FilePicker window.
[image]

I used Printing demo the Windows Universal Samples located in here
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing